# Trying to integrate Tap for Tap in my Application

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate tap for tap in my application. I am following their documentation from here: https://tapfortap.com/doc/android/integration. Everything seems fine up to when I added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.tapfortap.Banner
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="320dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I get the following message in the graphical layout:

```
com.tapfortap.Banner failed to instantiate.
```

and in the error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tapfortap.Banner.stopShowingAds(Unknown Source)
    at com.tapfortap.Banner.startShowingAds(Unknown Source)
    at com.tapfortap.Banner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1059)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateActivated(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:743)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.activated(CommonXmlEditor.java:416)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.LayoutWindowCoordinator.partActivated(LayoutWindowCoordinator.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService$6.run(PartService.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.partActivated(PartService.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$12.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4314)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.firePartActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$14(WorkbenchPage.java:4292)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$2.run(PartServiceImpl.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.setPart(PartServiceImpl.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activate(EclipseContext.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activateBranch(EclipseContext.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartActivationHistory.activate(PartActivationHistory.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$ActivationJob.run(StackRenderer.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

However thier website says that my app is registered, but I am not able to see any ads if I test it on a device or emulator, however I have added the testing meta tags in my Manifest and all thier permissions.

In Activity:

```
TapForTap.initialize(this, "*******************");
```

[image]

Comment: Have you added the API key in your manifest file ?

Comment: Yes I have, plus a meta tag for testing too!

Comment: Can you show your java file code ?

Comment: Please refer to the screen shot, if its not clear, Ill update the code in the question.

Comment: Screenshot is not clear that much that is why i am asking to post code. :)

Comment: Thats cause ".Banner" is not there in TapforTap.jar. I am surprised nowhere TapforTap has mentioned how to integrated with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because there is no class called `com.tapfortap.Banner`.

You need to use `com.tapfortap.sdk.Banner` from the new zip file https://github.com/tapfortap/Android/archive/master.zip.

Extract the zip file and again extract TapforTap.aar, you will get classes.jar use that in your program.